# in my application uitableview shrinks on iphone 5 ios 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

my tableview is working fine on iphone5,iphone6 & 6 plus iOS 8 but shrinks on iphone 5 iOS 7.1 and does not appears ons ipad of iOS 7.1.
m not using size classes,not even auto layout,itself working fine on other iOS versions,except iOs 7.1

Comment: Can you give some details? Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: help is apprieciated

Comment: no m not using auto layout

Comment: m using two storyboards one for iphone and another for ipad

Comment: Are you using Size Classes? Try to update your question with some more information plz